# LINQ: Load XML into a Dictionary with value equaling new custom class instances

Tags: c#, xml, linq, dictionary

Struggling a bit with two LINQ statements here. Basically I would like to convert the following two XML files into dictionaries (type-detail to follow). Here are snapshots of the XMLs:

**Offset XML:**

```
<Offsets>
  <PlayerStructBase>0xF24C10</PlayerStructBase>
  <HP>
    <offset>0x17e8</offset>
  </HP>
  <MaxHP>
    <offset>0x17ec</offset>
  </MaxHP>
</Offsets>
```

Desired output: `Dictionary<string, IntPtr>`. I have a method called GetPointerFromBaseOffsets(int[] offsets) that returns the IntPtr from a int array with offsets (example: `0x1234, 0x17e2`).

**Skills XML:**

```
<Skills>
  <Potion>
    <Cast>0.00</Cast>
    <ReCast>60.00</ReCast>
    <MPCost>0</MPCost>
  </Potion>
  <Ruin>
    <Cast>2.49</Cast>
    <ReCast>2.49</ReCast>
    <MPCost>9</MPCost>
  </Ruin>
</Skills>
```

Desired output: `Dictionary<string, Skill>`. Skill is a class with properties Cast, ReCast and MpCost among other things.

---

These are my attempts:

**Offset XML to Dictionary**

```
OffsetDictionary =
    XDocument.Load(folderPath+@"\offsets.xml")
        .XPathSelectElements("/Offsets/*[offset]")
        .ToDictionary(o => o.Name.LocalName,
            o => MemoryManager.GetPointerFromBaseOffsets(Enumerable.Cast<int>(o.Elements()).ToArray()));
```

**Skills XML to Dictionary**

```
SkillDictionary =
    XDocument.Load(folderPath + @"\skills.xml")
        .XPathSelectElements("/Skills/*")
        .ToDictionary(e => e.Name.LocalName, e => new Skill(e.Name.LocalName, (double)e.Element("Cast"), (double)e.Element("ReCast"), (int)e.Element("MPCost")));
```

---

**Question:** On the attempt at creating the Offset dictionary I get my first error-message (run-time), that it cannot be Cast. Could someone show me how to write these two blocks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Enumerable.Cast` doesn't perform *custom* conversions, which is what you want. You need to cast directly - but that's pretty simple:

```
OffsetDictionary =
    XDocument.Load(folderPath+@"\offsets.xml")
        .XPathSelectElements("/Offsets/*[offset]")
        .ToDictionary(o => o.Name.LocalName,
            o => MemoryManager.GetPointerFromBaseOffsets(o.Elements()
                                                          .Select(x => (int) x)
                                                          .ToArray()));
```

However, that assumes that your offsets are actually just plain decimal integers. In your case, they're not - they're in hex. You'll need to do a bit more work to parse those, e.g.

```
.Select(x => int.Parse(x.Value.Substring(2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier))
```

Alternatively, change your XML format so that the values are in decimal.

I'm not sure about your XPath expression though... I'm not an XPath expert by any means, but don't you just want all the elements directly beneath the root element? If so, you can just use

```
.Root.Elements()
```

instead of your `XPathSelectElements` call.

Comment: Thanks again Jon. I am getting this error message: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll". "Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format." I feel like I am missing something simple. Thanks in advance for guidance..

Comment: @Magnus: Well what's the stack trace for that error? Without knowing what's failing, it's hard to help more. But I'm not sure that your `o.Elements()` call is right either - are you sure about your XPath? I'll edit into my answer...

Comment: @Magnus: Ah, I've got it now - it's the fact that your offsets are in hex. Editing again.

Comment: Sweet, thanks, trying it now. The idea behind the 'XPathSelectElements' was that under HP, for instance, there might be several elements, all with the same tag (<offset>). Will test it now

Comment: @Magnus: But what are you trying to do with that? Surely the element you want is `HP`, not `offset`... you're already getting all the child elements later.

Comment: I might be making it more complex than it is. My goal is just to get the hex offsets for HP, MP, etc. out of the XML, and feed them as int[] into the GetPointerFromBaseOffsets (this method takes in a int[] and returns an IntPtr), to get a final Dictionary<string, IntPtr>.

Comment: @Magnus: I suspect you are - try the change I suggested for the XPath, and let me know if you're still running into problems.

Comment: AH, i think I see what the issue is. The first element "PlayerStructBase" does not follow the same layout as the rest. I have modified it so it does. Your suggestion(s) now work perfectly. Thanks a million as always!